# How to getId() within TextWatcher from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have a `ArrayList` of dynamic `EditText`. I want to implement `TextWatcher` on all `EditText`. I just used for Loop and easily implemented the `TextWatcher`, however I am unable to use `getTag()` there. Please suggest how can I get Tag on dynamically added `EditText`

```
for (int z = 0; z < allwtEditTextList.size(); z++) {                

allwtEditTextList.get(z).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                            int after) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Need getTag() here
                    }
                });
           }
```

Comment: what you want to achieve dude

Comment: I am doing some calculations for that I need the tag of respective edittext, But afterTextChanged doesnt have View parameter and the calculations need to be done on KeyUp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
    final ArrayList<EditText> allwtEditTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    .........
    for (int z = 0; z < allwtEditTextList.size(); z++) {
        final int pos = z;
        allwtEditTextList.get(z).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Need getTag() here
                allwtEditTextList.get(pos).getTag();
            }
        });
    }
```